How to Sign XML Documents in Python Using a Private Key from Windows Certificate Store?
I am trying to sign XML documents in Python using a private key that is stored in the Windows Certificate Store. I have a digital certificate installed on my machine, which includes both the public and private keys. The certificate can be seen in the Windows Certificate Manager under Current User -> Personal -> Certificates.
My Environment:
Python version: 3.11.5
Platform: Windows 10
OpenSSL version: 24.1.0
Cryptography version: 42.0.7
pycryptodome version: 3.18.0
pywin32 version: 306
signxml version: 3.2.2
wincertstore version: 0.2
What I Have Tried:
I have attempted to use ctypes and win32crypt to access the private key and sign the XML document, but I keep encountering "access violation" errors. Below is the latest version of my code, which is still not working:

import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, Listbox, Scrollbar, END, Frame, Label, Button
import wincertstore
import binascii
import logging
from lxml import etree
from signxml import XMLSigner
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import pkcs1_15
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from OpenSSL import crypto
import win32crypt

logging.basicConfig(filename="error_log.txt", level=logging.ERROR)

def try_unhexlify(data):
try:
return binascii.unhexlify(data)
except binascii.Error as e:
logging.error(f"Error converting thumbprint: {data}")
logging.error(e)
raise e

def get_cert_thumbprint(cert):
try:
cert_bytes = cert.get_encoded()
cert_obj = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, cert_bytes)
thumbprint = cert_obj.digest("sha1").decode('utf-8').replace(":", "").upper()
return thumbprint
except Exception as e:
logging.error("Error getting certificate thumbprint")
logging.error(e)
raise e

def get_private_key_and_cert(cert, pin):
try:
cert_bytes = cert.get_encoded()
cert_context = win32crypt.CertCreateCertificateContext(win32crypt.X509_ASN_ENCODING | win32crypt.PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, cert_bytes)

prov_handle, key_spec, free_handle = win32crypt.CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(cert_context, 0, None)

key_blob = win32crypt.CryptExportKey(prov_handle, None, win32crypt.PRIVATEKEYBLOB, 0)
private_key = RSA.import_key(key_blob)

cert_pem = crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert_context)

return private_key, cert_pem
except Exception as e:
logging.error("Error obtaining private key and certificate in PEM format")
logging.error(e)
raise e

def sign_document(private_key, cert_pem, data):
try:
signer = XMLSigner()
signed_xml = signer.sign(data, key=private_key.export_key(), cert=cert_pem.decode())
return signed_xml
except Exception as e:
logging.error("Error signing the document")
logging.error(e)
raise e

def confirm_certificate():
selected_cert = cert_listbox.get(cert_listbox.curselection())
with wincertstore.CertSystemStore("MY") as store:
for cert in store.itercerts(usage=wincertstore.CLIENT_AUTH):
if cert.get_name() == selected_cert:
cert_thumbprint = get_cert_thumbprint(cert).upper().replace(" ", "")
logging.info(f"Certificate confirmed: {cert.get_name()} with thumbprint: {cert_thumbprint}")

pin = "your-pin-here"  # Replace 'your-pin-here' with your actual PIN
private_key, cert_pem = get_private_key_and_cert(cert, pin)

xml_content = "<test>Important content</test>"
root = etree.fromstring(xml_content)

signed_root = sign_document(private_key, cert_pem, root)

signed_xml_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f"signed_{cert_thumbprint}.xml")
with open(signed_xml_path, "wb") as f:
f.write(etree.tostring(signed_root, pretty_print=True))

messagebox.showinfo("Success", f"Signed document saved at: {signed_xml_path}")
return

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Digital Signature")
root.configure(bg="#93C5FD")

frame_certs = Frame(root, bg="#93C5FD")
frame_certs.pack(pady=10)

Label(frame_certs, text="Certificate:", bg="#E0F2FE").pack(pady=5)
cert_listbox = Listbox(frame_certs, width=50, height=10)
cert_listbox.pack(pady=5)
cert_scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame_certs, command=cert_listbox.yview)
cert_scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
cert_listbox.config(yscrollcommand=cert_scrollbar.set)

confirm_button = Button(frame_certs, text="Confirm selection", command=confirm_certificate)
confirm_button.pack(pady=5)

with wincertstore.CertSystemStore("MY") as store:
for cert in store.itercerts(usage=wincertstore.CLIENT_AUTH):
cert_listbox.insert(END, cert.get_name())

root.mainloop()



Error:
result = acquire_key_func(
cert_context,
0,
None,
ctypes.byref(key_handle),
ctypes.byref(key_spec),
ctypes.byref(caller_free)
         )

I keep encountering an "access violation" error at the following line:
How can I correctly access the private key from the Windows Certificate Store and use it to sign an XML document in Python? Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated.

the code needs indentation.

Is the key in Windows cert store marked as exportable or can't it be exported?
